# Instantaneous query timeout in Aurora MySQL (using jOOQ, MariaDB driver)

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, jooq, amazon-aurora

My Java application works fine when I execute a query using jOOQ and the MariaDB driver for connecting to an Aurora MySQL database. In plain SQL my query looks like this, and notice the timestamps:

```
select
  A.id, B.x, B.y,
  coalesce(A.modified, A.created) as modified
from
  A join B on A.b_id = B.id
where
  A.created between date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and now()
  or A.modified between date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) and now();
```

But when I run the same query with a bigger timestamp interval, it fails *immediately* with a timeout error (AFAIK no actual timeout had a chance to happen), for example this query will fail at once (again, notice the timestamps):

```
select
  A.id, B.x, B.y,
  coalesce(A.modified, A.created) as modified
from
  A join B on A.b_id = B.id
where
  A.created between date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) and now()
  or A.modified between date_sub(now(), interval 1 month) and now();
```

The above query succeeds when connecting directly through a MySQL console, and I have some other long-running queries in my system using the same stack that run successfully, with no timeout complaints. The problem only occurs from my Java application, with *some* (but not all!) queries that have a big time interval - say, a month (but no with an interval of a couple of days). My stack includes:

- Open JDK 8
- jOOQ 3.11
- MariaDB Connector/J 2.2
- Aurora MySQL 5.6.10a

The stack trace in my logs (attached below) shows "Connection timed out" and "Read timed out" all over the place. Any ideas why a longer interval in the query causes an instantaneous timeout? I'll provide more details if needed, just ask in the comments.

**UPDATE:** I changed my driver to use the standard MySQL Java driver, and the query now works! I'll leave this question open, because I'd still like to understand *why* this is happening, what's broken with the MariaDB driver, and if it's possible to find a workaround (because I'd prefer to use the MariaDB driver.)

```
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [<query>]; (conn=349133) Communications link failure with primary host <host>. Connection timed out
at org.jooq_3.11.4.MARIADB.debug(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.translate(Tools.java:2384) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:811) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:364) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:393) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchLazy(AbstractResultQuery.java:380) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchStream(AbstractResultQuery.java:351) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetchStreamInto(AbstractResultQuery.java:356) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
<redacted>
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_222]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_222]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: (conn=349133) Communications link failure with primary host <host>. Connection timed out
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:198) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.getException(ExceptionMapper.java:110) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbStatement.executeExceptionEpilogue(MariaDbStatement.java:228) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:216) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3483) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
... 17 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Communications link failure with primary host <host>. Connection timed out
on HostAddress{host='<host>', port=3306},master=true. Driver has reconnect connection
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.AbstractMastersListener.throwFailoverMessage(AbstractMastersListener.java:517) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.handleFailOver(FailoverProxy.java:354) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.executeInvocation(FailoverProxy.java:292) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.invoke(FailoverProxy.java:263) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3483) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
... 17 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Read timed out
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.handleIoException(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1786) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1344) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1323) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:252) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.MastersSlavesListener.invoke(MastersSlavesListener.java:217) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.executeInvocation(FailoverProxy.java:270) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.invoke(FailoverProxy.java:263) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3483) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
... 17 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:286) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:237) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:207) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.readPacket(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1342) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.getResult(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:1323) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractQueryProtocol.executeQuery(AbstractQueryProtocol.java:252) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_222]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.impl.MastersSlavesListener.invoke(MastersSlavesListener.java:217) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.executeInvocation(FailoverProxy.java:270) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.failover.FailoverProxy.invoke(FailoverProxy.java:263) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.executeInternal(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:209) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.execute(MariaDbPreparedStatementClient.java:150) ~[Mariadb-java-client-2.2.x.jar:?]
at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:209) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.Tools.executeStatementAndGetFirstResultSet(Tools.java:3483) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:268) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:350) ~[jooq-3.11.4.jar:?]
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aurora configuration has a default socket timeout of 10s: see `socketTimeout` documentation in https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/about-mariadb-connector-j/:

> Default: 0 (standard configuration) or 10000ms (using "aurora" failover configuration).

Changing that value to 0 means no timeout.

This can be done using connection string, like `jdbc:mariadb:aurora://myHost/db?socketTimeout=0`

Comment: Good sir, your solution worked. Thank you very much!